# Reading/Writing INI w/ variable Section Name

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, ini

Good afternoon folks -

I'm working on reading/writing an external file that is created and managed by a 3rd party that uses .INI structured files as its scripting language.  I've got a wrapper working pretty well however, the section names are static with a unique number at the end ([GENERAL-1]) so that you have have the same task more than once.  I am using VB.NET w/ VS2008.

My code below can successfully read a key from a section that is hardcoded but I'd like the key to be generic.

**INI**

```
test.ini
[GENERAL-1]
SUPPRESSTASKERRORS=Y
TASKERRORSENDJOB=Y
```

**Code:**

```
Declare Function GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias    
"GetPrivateProfileStringA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As  
String, ByVal lpDefault As String, ByVal lpReturnedString As String, ByVal nSize As   
Long, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long

Declare Function WriteProfileString Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias 
"WritePrivateProfileStringA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As   
String, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long



' Read INI file
    Dim uname As String ' receives the value read from the INI file
    Dim slength As Long ' receives length of the returned string
    Dim OriginalMJB As String = "c:\test\test.ini"
    uname = Space(1024)

slength = GetPrivateProfileString("General-1", "SUPPRESSTASKERRORS", "anonymous", 
uname, 1024, OriginalMJB)
```

Notice the General-1 above, if I have the value hardcoded as -1 I can read the input .ini file without a problem.  Any thoughts on how I can get and use the value left of the hyphen?

Any help is appreciated!

--George

Comment: Does this not work? `Dim section As String = "General"
slength = GetPrivateProfileString(section & "-1", "SUPPRESSTASKERRORS", "anonymous", uname, 1024, OriginalMJB)`

Comment: Can you not create a loop to call General-1, General-2, etc? You can call Getprivate... with NULLS in the first 1 or 2 params to get lists of what is present. See MSDN docs.

Comment: Are you saying you want a function that can be called with different suffix values?

Comment: The hyphen one (-1) can be any value.  The hyphen just makes the section unique so you can have multiple sections with the same name such as IMPORT-1 and IMPORT-2 are then considered two separate sections.  I really want the -1 to be variable where one script might be GENERAL-1 and another GENERAL-2..

Make Sense?

Comment: Maybe a regex can be used to look at the beginning of the section??

Comment: If it's a new application, you should look at .xml files

Comment: Sigh, its not a new application..  I'm writing a utility to support an existing product which will give a user a front end UI that is simpler then the existing product.  They exclusively use this structured file format so I'm stuck using it..

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way.  From here you should be able to make SectionNo equal the specific section you want.

```
Dim section As String = "General"
Dim SectionNo as String = "-"
Dim Number as Integer = 1
SectionNo += Number.ToString
slength = GetPrivateProfileString(section + SectionNo, "SUPPRESSTASKERRORS", "anonymous", uname, 1024, OriginalMJB)
```

Here's a couple of options

```
    Dim SectionName As String = "General-1"
    Dim SectionCategorie As String = ""
    Dim Section As String = ""

    'Using Split - It returns an array so you can load the results into an array   
    'or just call it and load the specific index each time.
    SectionCategorie = Split(SectionName, "-")(0)
    Section = Split(SectionName, "-")(1)

    'Using Substring

    SectionCategorie = SectionName.Substring(0, SectionName.IndexOf("-"))
    Section = SectionName.Substring(SectionName.IndexOf("-") + 1)
```

Comment: The "number" or value after the hyphen is variable, could be numeric or alhpa characters.  Trying to get a left/right expression to work so I can parse the section name and only take value to the hyphen..

Comment: I added a couple of options for you to look at